# django model migration problem table already exist

Tags: django, database, legacy

hello i have a legacy database which contain a users table and I want just to add to this table some field and override abstract base user of Django model auth
the problem is when I am trying to migrate is says that the table users is already exist in database

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
import sha512_crypt
import time

# function that return actual timestamp
def actual_epoch_time():
    return int(time.time())
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,username,password=None):
        user = self.model(email = normalize_email(email),username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
    def create_superuser(self,email,username,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(username=username,password=password,email=email)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()
        return user

#here is the abstracted user model from xui database with additional fields
class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date_registered = models.IntegerField(default=actual_epoch_time())
    last_login = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    member_group_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    credits = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    reseller_dns = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    owner_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    override_packages = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    hue = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    theme = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
 

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'users'

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = sha512_crypt.encrypt(raw_password,rounds=200000)
    def check_password(self, raw_password):
        return sha512_crypt.verify(raw_password,self.password)
```

Comment: Did you manage to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` field on settings.py file?

Comment: yes already done in setting.py . if I drop the users table directly from database and I run migrate it create the table but if the table are loaded with data it does not work . I can't drop my production table because I need all the users information

Comment: I think what you can do here is write a pre-migration script to gather all user information and DROP the previous USER table add gathered details into new model.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to extend the user model, in this situation you must drop the database and make it again with new changes for user table, but if you have important data in the database you should first take a backup from it and after dropping the db insert it to the new db, but it always suggested make an abstract model from the user model in the beginning of the project for future changes.

Comment: already done but it does not work .